# TypeError: 'rv_frozen' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python, scipy

I tried to run my `Grid Search CV` with parameter that is set. But somehow it says `TypeError: 'rv_frozen' object cannot be interpreted as an integer` which happens in line `grid.fit(X_train,y_train)`. Why the fitting returns error?  What should i do to fix it?

```
final['cluster'] = dbcpca
final = pd.get_dummies(final)
# sns.heatmap(final.corr(),annot=True)


X = np.array(final.drop(['unemployed'],1))
y = np.array(final['unemployed'])

X = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)
y = StandardScaler().fit_transform(y.reshape(-1,1))

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)

xgb_model = xgb.XGBRegressor()

params = {
    "colsample_bytree": [uniform(0.7, 0.3)],
    "gamma": [uniform(0, 0.5)],
    "learning_rate": [uniform(0.03, 0.3)], # default 0.1 
    "max_depth": [randint(2, 6)], # default 3
    "n_estimators": [randint(100, 150)], # default 100
    "subsample": [uniform(0.6, 0.4)]
}

grid = GridSearchCV(estimator= xgb_model,param_grid =params,
                    refit=True,verbose=1,cv =10,n_jobs=-1)
grid.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

Comment: `uniform(0.7,0.3)` is a frozen random variable (just print it somewhere to see it). You should pass a list of integers/floats

Comment: Change `uniform(0.7, 0.3)` to `uniform.rvs(0.7, 0.3)`. Likewise for the other uses of `uniform` and `randint`.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser it works, thank you sir